# Can a kitchen faucet be installed by someone with no experience?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I bought a pull out kitchen faucet online. Can this be installed by someone (me) with no experience?

Comment: Read the instructions and then you can be the judge as to if installing it is within your capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- on the sink
- on the faucet
- on the location
- on the tools you have
- on your skill level (in general, not experience on sinks)

The two biggest issues in installing a faucet are reaching the components that need to be tightened and properly sealing the connections and the base.

The place where a faucet is attached (mechanically) and has its supply lines connected (plumbing) tend to be difficult to reach once the sink is in place.  That is why these are often attached before a sink is mounted in a cabinet. You end up lying on your back under the sink trying to reach above you into a small tight area with little room to swing a tightening tool.

There are specialty tools that make it somewhat easier such as these

**[basin wrench](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-12-in-Steel-Basin-Wrench-T151/100006605)**

[image: basin wrench]

**[faucet tool](http://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Faucet-and-Sink-Installer-Tool-27018/100595073)**

[image: faucet tool]

Some fixtures can have their connecting supply lines pre-attached to the faucet end, and then dropped through the sink hole. Then the mechanical connection is made. The connection to the supply pipe is usually easier to reach than the connection on the faucet end once installed.

It is important to use the right kind of connection depending on your supply line. Most are [screw on connectors](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-3-8-in-OD-x-1-2-in-IPS-x-20-in-Faucet-Supply-Line-Braided-Stainless-Steel-7223-20-38-2/203082353) and need teflon tape to seal the connection.

[image: faucet connector]

Also the faucet needs to be seated in plumbers putty to seal around its edges and prevent water leakage to the underside of the sink.

Most faucets have reasonable instructions and it's not rocket surgery, but you need to assess your general skills and comfort level. Even reasonably skilled folks manage to cause leaks when installing fixtures that can damage a floor or a ceiling below. (I know my wife will eventually forgive me for the ripples in the new plasterboard in the room below the bathroom sink I fixed.)

Comment: Not many things are rocket surgery!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your supply lines are the same size - which in most cases they would be this is as easy turning off the water supply (either to the area of the house, the whole house, or hopefully just shut-offs under the sink), then uninstall old faucet (adjustable wrench, utility knife), and installing new faucet (adjustable wrench, reading directions).

This is the usual case.  Some foreign (to you) faucets may have different sizings which require plumbing work.

For someone with little to no experience (and doesn't have problems with finding tools) this job is 2 hours.  The hardest part is getting under your sink to do most of the screwing and unscrewing.